# Ajax POST not reaching server, returning 400 only in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, apache, firefox

I have a Flask server running in Apache that returns an HTML page with a button to submit an AJAX POST request to a relative URL. In Firefox, the AJAX call fails **immediately** with a 400, logging `POST response ERROR code: 400`. Logging the xhr object **or** the data parameter to the console results in `<unavailable>`, with its `responseText` attribute as `undefined`. The response is exactly the same, regardless of what URL is passed to AJAX. The absolute URL (http://thehostname.com/path/send-email) also gives the same result.

Apache's `access.log` shows no request coming in at the time of the AJAX requests. The request does not come up at all in Firefox's "Network" tab of the dev tools. The request works fine in Chrome with all other conditions the same, as well is with cURL.

The code is below. Please help!

HTML:

```
<img width="20px" src="mail.png" alt="" onerror="this.style.display='none'" onclick="sendEmail('val1', 'val2', 'val3')">
```

JS:

```
    function sendEmail(val1, val2, val3) {
        val1 = prompt('Prompt2 for ' + val2 + ':', val1);
        console.log('Val1: '+ val1);
        if(val1) {
            let xhr = $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'send-email',
                // Tried with and without stringify
                data: JSON.stringify({param1: val1, param2: val2, param3: val3}),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'text',
                cache: false,
                traditional: true
            }).done(function(){
                alert("Sent!");
            }).fail(function(data){
                console.log("Info:");
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                alert('Failed to send');
            });
        }
        console.log("Ret false");
        return false;
    };
```

Python endpoint:

```
@app.route('/autorack_testing_report/send-email', methods=['POST'])
@app.route('/send-email', methods=['POST'])
def send_email():
    print("Send email") # Not getting printed
    info = request.form or request.json
    if not (info and info.get('param1') and info.get('param2')):
        abort(400, 'Must supply recipient and ticket')
    send_to_list = re.split(',|;', info['param1'])
    send_to = []
    for s in send_to_list:
        if s.strip():
            send_to.append(s.strip() + '@domain.com')
    send_to = ','.join(send_to)
    ticket = info['ticket']
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP('mysmtphost', 25)
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = 'subject'
    msg['From'] = msg['To'] = send_to
    msg.attach(MIMEText('somecontent', 'plain'))
    smtp.sendmail(send_to, send_to, msg.as_string())
    smtp.quit()
    resp = make_response('Success', 200)
    resp.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
    return resp
```

Firefox console output:

```
Val1: myinput
Ret false
POST response ERROR code: 400
POST response ERROR code: 400
Info:
undefined
```

No Python output, since Apache isn't receiving the request.

Comment: The code 400 means bad request. So you have invalid syntax on server side.

Comment: Please add the function that handle ajax request. The python code.

Comment: What happens if try to access the same URL using curl?

Comment: You better check if you are working with local files, or on server - check if Firefox URI is same as on another browser. Copy from Chrome to Firefox.

Comment: @ASSILITaher since Apache's access log isn't showing any incoming requests, is there any use in showing the Python code if it's not being reached anyway? I'll add it if it's helpful but the request doesn't seem to be making it as far as the server

Comment: @RandyCasburn updated.

Comment: Whats the full url thats being called in the network tab?

Comment: @Rastalamm for some reason the AJAX requests are not appearing in the Firefox network tab at all, only as errors in the console.

Comment: Have you tried setting the full url in your Ajax request? Something like: `url: 'localhost:3000/api/send-email'` instead of `url: 'send-email'`

Comment: @Rastalamm I have, got the same result. Edited to reflect, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Can you add in both of your console.log outputs?

Comment: Maybe is just me, but AJAX seems a bit easy to misuse. If nothing works I suggest you to try fetch-api

Answer (score 0):

The 400 Bad Request response status code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing). where does 'send-email' point to?

Comment: It points to a Flask endpoint behind apache, but the response is exactly the same, regardless of what URL is supplied - Apache isn't even receiving the request.